# MongoDB with multi core instance

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a "large" EC2 instance with 2 cores running MongoDB as part of a Replicaset.

Does MongoDB use both cores in parallel by default or do I need to make some configuration change?

Comment: It uses multiple cores by default. Just make sure you disable THP.